# My php table changed the false row in my db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a PHP beginner & have a question xd
Whenever I click on the submit button, the data of the last user in the PHP table are changed.

Could somebody check on it?

```
 <?php
foreach ($db->results() as $unpaid){

    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <tr><td>
            <?=$unpaid->id?>
            <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?=$unpaid->id?>">
            </td>
            <td><?=$unpaid->username?>
            </td>
            <td><?=$unpaid->bitcoinadress?></td>
            <td><?=$unpaid->points?></td>
            <td><?=$unpaid->requestdate?></td>
            <td><?=$unpaid->status?></td>
            <td>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br/>

            </td>


            </tr>


<?php } ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
$id = $POST_['user'];
$db->update("payment_request", $id, ["status"=>"Paid"]);

?>

</form>
</table>
```

Comment: `$POST_` -> `$_POST`

Comment: Thanks v much i have chaged this but my problem is still there

Comment: You will also need braces for the `if` statement just before it. (`if(isset($_POST['submit'])) `) to group the setting the ID and the `update`

Comment: i got the same problem .. i have tested this too... (isset($_POST['submit'])) { $id = $POST_['user'];
$db->update("payment_request", $id, ["status"=>"Paid"]);} but every time it will be changed on the last table row

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<form>` as the parent of `<tr>`. `<tr>` has to be the child of `<table>` or `<tbody>`.

Comment: You also have `<form>` inside the loop, so there's a new one on every row, but `</form>` is outside the loop so there's only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `<form>` around a `<tr>`. You need to put the form inside one of the `<td>` tags.

```
<table>
<?php
foreach ($db->results() as $unpaid){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?=$unpaid->id?> </td>
        <td><?=$unpaid->username?> </td>
        <td><?=$unpaid->bitcoinadress?></td>
        <td><?=$unpaid->points?></td>
        <td><?=$unpaid->requestdate?></td>
        <td><?=$unpaid->status?></td>
        <td>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?=$unpaid->id?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br/>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
    $id = $POST_['user'];
$db->update("payment_request", $id, ["status"=>"Paid"]);

?>
</table>
```

Comment: It worrrrrksssss :)))) Thanks a lot